# Simplifying x + 1/x < 2

Tags: inequality, fractions

I can't seem to find where my algebra is wrong in my assumption that x + 1/x < 2 can be simplified to (x-1)^2 < 0.

I start with x in the set of real numbers such that x + 1/x < 2 so I then subtract x from both sides leading to

1/x < 2 - x

I then multiply x to both sides to give me

1 < 2x-x^2

and then subtract one

0 < -x^2 +2x -1

I then add one to the other side and subtract 2x and add x^2 to get

x^2 -2x + 1 < 0

and then factor and simplify to

(x-1)^2 < 0

I am simply not seeing where I am breaking rules. **I understand how to simplify this inequality I am more wondering why what I did in the above steps is invalid**.

It has been a very long time since I have dealt with inequalities so that may be why I am not seeing what is probably an obvious mistake. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Edit: x is a real number and I understand that (x-c)^2 >=0 for all x and c in Real Numbers but I am wondering where my algebra went wrong to lead me to this contradiction.

Comment: Now for real $x,$  $$(x-1)^2\ge0$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the existing solutions, since OP asks for *why* the calculations are wrong, I am going to write a few lines.

> $$\frac1x < 2 - x \quad(\text{correct step})$$
>   I then multiply $x$ to both sides to give me $$1 < 2x-x^2.\quad(\text{incorrect deduction})$$

The logic is that the inequality is preserved when both sides are multiplied by *a* positive number; while it is *reversed* when they are multiplied by *a* negative number.
$$a>0 \text{ and } b<c \implies ab<ac \\ a<0 \text{ and } b<c \implies ab>ac$$
You have to divide two cases.
$$\begin{cases}1 < 2x-x^2 \qquad x>0 \\ 1>2x-x^2 \qquad x<0\end{cases}$$
Rewrite them as squares.
$$\begin{cases}-(x-1)^2 < 0 \qquad x>0 \text{ rejected} \\ (x-1)^2 \qquad x<0 \text{ always true} \end{cases}$$
This allows us to conclude that $x<0$ is the necessary and sufficient condition for the inequality $x+1/x<2$.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for when I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when multiplying an inequality throughout by something (whether it be a variable or a constant), you need to consider its *sign*.

Here, $x$ is a real variable, so we have to consider cases. We can rule out $x = 0$ as it leaves one term on the LHS undefined. So just consider $x>0$ and $x<0$.

For the first case, the inequality does not change direction, leaving us with $(x-1)^2<0$. Obviously this has no real solution, so we can conclude that $x>0$ cannot satisfy the original inequality.

For the second case, the inequality changes direction, giving us $(x-1)^2>0$, which holds trivially true for all real $x$. This means that *all* $x<0$ satisfy the original inequality.

Comment: So when we can't be sure of the sign of x then we must try to move other variables around because we don't know what will happen to the inequality?

Comment: @Luke No, I'm saying that when you can't be sure of the sign of something you're multiplying, consider cases for that something (positive, negative, zero (if applicable)). When you multiply by a negative quantity, inequalities change direction.

Comment: And if x is negative then, like in your answer, the result is different. That makes everything crystal crystal clear. The answer distributes out all the different ways this could be perceived. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not equivalent to $(x-1)^2<0$ because $x$ can be negative.

We need to make following steps.
$$x+\frac{1}{x}<2$$ it's
$$x+\frac{1}{x}-2<0$$ or
$$\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x}<0$$ or $$\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}<0.$$
If we need to solve this inequality then we obtain $x<0.$

Comment: I see that way, but why can't I subtract x to both sides as the first step is really what I am wondering.

Comment: Because $x$ can be negative.

Comment: Could you add that to your answer so I may accept it. I didn't even consider that the algebraic rules will be restricted based on my conditions of x. Holy crap thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I added. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from AM GM, for all positive $x$, $$x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2$$

Thus the given inequality can only be satisfied when $x < 0$